# Change-up in floating divs behaviour when they overlap

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two divs. They can both contain variable sized content.

One needs to float left, the other needs to float right. Or rather, one needs to hug the left side of the parent and the other the right (in-case someone has a non-floating solution). But when they overlap (i.e when the browser is shrunk to a size that makes the floated left div come into contact with the floated right) I want them to clear, or stack one-on-top-of-the-other as if they were both floating left without enough space to fission.

Is this even possible?

Some HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-title">
        <h1>
            Title (variable length)
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="header-menu">
        <h2>
            Menu1 Menu2 Menu3 Menu4 Menu5 Menu6 Menu7 (variable length)
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
#header{

    overflow:auto;

}

#header-title{

    float:left;

}

#header-menu{

    float:right;

}
```

It's worth mentioning that the desired behaviour is somewhat in the realms of responsive web-design, but I want it to behave this way without the `@media` query. The `viewport` meta tag will be used eventually, but for the moment I just want it responding correctly in a desktop setting.

Good luck...

Comment: Seems as though the title is wrong. What you have already "stops floating divs from overlapping": http://jsfiddle.net/K8fnc/. The key feature you asked for was "How to swap from floating right to floating left without a media query". I would try to answer that for you but I can't think of a way to do it without media queries (unless you want jQuery).

Comment: You're right. I didn't clarify that I was more interested in the floats aligning left when they start to overlap. The problem with a media query is that I would have to make assumptions about the size of the floating div in order to implement it. If the total width of the divs only ends up being 600px and my `@media` query kicks in at 480px, the desktop version of the website would likely keep the right div floated right even when it has dropped below my left div. I figured there may be a fix with a good wrapping structure and perhaps some absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

http://jsfiddle.net/K8fnc/3/

```
#header{

overflow:auto;

}

#header-title{

    float: left;
}
```

If you take away float: right on the second div, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this is not what I'm looking for as the text just wraps around the `header-left` as much as it can before it clears. I need it to either fall to the right or fall completely left depending on how much space it has.